# SVNKit memory leak: SVNLog.run() creates thread that is never killed

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, svnkit

My Tomcat webapp queries SVN for commits between two points in time:

```
    final SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("svn+ssh://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx");

SVNSSHAuthentication sshCredentials = SVNSSHAuthentication.newInstance(
    Constants.SVN_USERNAME,
    Constants.PRIVATE_KEY,
    Constants.PRIVATE_KEY_PASS_PHRASE,
    Constants.SVN_PORT,
    Constants.ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_TO_BE_STORED,
    url,
    Constants.CREDENTIAL_IS_NOT_PARTIAL);

ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = new BasicAuthenticationManager(new SVNAuthentication[] { sshCredentials });
SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {

  svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

  final SvnLog log = svnOperationFactory.createLog();
  log.addRange(SvnRevisionRange.create(SVNRevision.create(new Date(1444612639000l)), SVNRevision.create(new Date(1444737236000l))));
  log.setDiscoverChangedPaths(true);
  log.setLimit(100l);
  log.setReceiver(new ISvnObjectReceiver<SVNLogEntry>() {
    @Override
    public void receive(SvnTarget target, SVNLogEntry logEntry) throws SVNException {
      System.out.println(logEntry);
    }
  });
  log.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromURL(url));
  log.run();
}
catch (SVNException e) {
  throw e;
} finally {
  svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

Problem: each time the webapp is reloaded or redeployed, there are a few threads that are not killed, resulting in duplicated classes in the Permanent Generation:
[image]

These are the threads that are created each time `log.run()` is called. You see there are two groups - the first group belong to the previous instance of the webapp - which has already been stopped - for some reason they're not killed together with the webapp.
[image]

Stack trace of thread 6 and thread 11:

```
Thread dump at 5:11.060.359

* Thread group "main":

  Thread "Thread-6":
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[ ], int, int, int)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[ ], int, int, int)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[ ], int, int)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.fill_buffer()
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.internal_read(byte[ ], int, int)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock()
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(byte[ ], int, int)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(byte[ ], int, int)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop()
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run()
    at java.lang.Thread.run()
```

If I comment out `log.run()` the threads are not created and thus no resources are leaked. So the problem is because of `log.run()` - somehow the thread is not killed when the webapp is killed.

`svnOperationFactory.dispose();` at the end of the code doesn't seem to dispose anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, leaks in third party software really depend on the version. Your question doesn't say what version of SVNKit you're on. So as a first first crack at a response, I'll ask if you are using the latest version of SVNKit. I've been researching a few candidate memory leaks with SVNKit including:

1. [No dispose called on SVNClients](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.subclipse.user/14565)
2. [Orphaned threads with svn+ssh connections](https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-467)

and a few others. However, they all appear to be for older versions of SVNKit so I'd try to upgrade first if possible.

Comment: I'm using tomcat 8, svnkit 1.8.11, they're all newest versions to date.

Comment: Another dumb question: Have you taken heap dumps between several deployments, observing newly created threads after each deployment, ensuring that this just isn't an issue where are few more threads are created on the first/second redeploy?

Comment: Yes I spent 2 days on this issues and have done every trick in the book - I'm sure the threads are products of SVNLog.run()

Comment: Fukuzawa, I take it you are referring to the class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SVNLog correct? I downloaded the source code and there are two classes names SVNLog - hence the question.

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio, I checked out the source code for package on my local host. You mentioned that you tried `svnOperationFactory.dispose()`, but to no avail. Have you tried adding `log.cancel()` to your `finally` block or another preferable place in your code?